# issue with spawning multiples of the same snake food

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

It is a simple snake game, but I am having a problem with the snake food. I spawn a new food with `generateSnakeFood();` and that works fine, but when I try to create multiple snake food, it just repaints a new snake food in a different location, is this because there can only be one of the SnakeFood so the brush paints a new one in another area. If so, how would I fix it so I can have multiple of the same snake food?

```
private Square SnakeFood = new Square();
private void generateSnakeFood()
        {
            int maxXPosition = pictureBox1.Size.Width / GameSetting.Width;
            int maxYPosition = pictureBox1.Size.Height / GameSetting.Height;
            SnakeFood = new Square { X = random.Next(0, maxXPosition), Y = random.Next(0, maxYPosition) };

        }
private void UpdateGame(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
 Graphics canvas = e.Graphics
 canvas.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red,
                                   new Rectangle(
                                       SnakeFood.X * GameSetting2.Width2,
                                       SnakeFood.Y * GameSetting2.Width2,
                                       GameSetting2.Width2, GameSetting2.Height2
                                              ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this because there can only be one of the SnakeFood so the brush
> paints a new one in another area

Yes. Even though you do a `new Square` you are still re-instianciating the same variable. The drawing portion of your code just read 1 variable and draw 1 `Square`. You will need to use a collection of some sort so you can have a different count. It does also mean you will need to change your code where you detect collision and where you eat the food and remove it.

There are many ways to achieve this one could be to use a `List` and change your code like this

```
private List<Square> SnakeFoods = new List<Square>();
private void generateSnakeFood()
{
    // create new random food using the new method
    // doesn't mean it's valid yet
    Square newFood = GenerateRandomFood();

    // you need to make sure there is not another food at that same location
    // in the collection or else you have a duplicate.
    // if there is a duplicate you need to generate a new one until it's unique.
    // Here I use linq, a feature available on List to check if
    // you already have a food at that location in order to prevent doubles
    // While it find ANY item in the collection that has the same X and Y it regenerate a new random food. 
    while(SnakeFoods.Any(snakeFood => snakeFood.X == newFood.X && snakeFood.Y == newFood.Y))
    {
        newFood = GenerateRandomFood();
    }
    
    // when the code get's here the loop above had taken care that 
    // newFood is not a duplicate so we can add it
    SnakeFoods.Add(newFood);

}

// this will just return a new random food without storing it as we dont know if it's good
private Square GenerateRandomFood()
{
    int maxXPosition = pictureBox1.Size.Width / GameSetting.Width;
    int maxYPosition = pictureBox1.Size.Height / GameSetting.Height;

    // just return new random food
    return new Square { X = random.Next(0, maxXPosition), Y = random.Next(0, maxYPosition) };
}
```

The drawing portion need a slight change to loop on the collection and draw all foods in it.

```
private void UpdateGame(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics canvas = e.Graphics


    // one minor change is to loop to draw all foods (squares)
    foreach(Square SnakeFood in SnakeFoods)
    {
        canvas.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red,
                             new Rectangle(
                                 SnakeFood.X * GameSetting2.Width2,
                                 SnakeFood.Y * GameSetting2.Width2,
                                 GameSetting2.Width2, GameSetting2.Height2));
    }
}
```

Despite all these changes showing the working code of multiple food source, you still have to work out your code where you check if you have eaten one and how to remove it from the list. I left it out so you still have work to do and things to learn.

Comment: I get how to check if the snake have eaten the food, but as i discovered I need a way to remove the food from the list, now I know there is `remove`and `removeAt`, but as I discoverd get again I dont really know which one is nr1 or nr3 food. Do you know a way or can direct me to a link where I can read more up on this ?

Comment: ok I got it no need to answer